# No "(.:format)" in Rails 3.1 when trying to route site root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Since upgrading to Rails 3.1, I've been having a problem with my site's routing. Previously, with Rails 3.0, I was able to do this in my router config:

```
resources :quotes, :path => ""
root :to => "quotes#index"
```

That would give me routes like `GET /(.:format)` and such, which is what I want since the `index` action of my `QuotesController` can also return data in JSON, XML and ATOM.

Now, since upgrading to Rails 3.1, the routes have been showing up like this: `GET /`. The `(.:format)` is gone, and trying to access the `/.atom` URL doesn't work anymore. How can I get this functionality back?

**EDIT**: "rake routes CONTROLLER=quotes" outputs the following:

```
   about_quotes GET    /about(.:format)    {:action=>"about", :controller=>"quotes"}
     top_quotes GET    /top(.:format)      {:action=>"top", :controller=>"quotes"}
  random_quotes GET    /random(.:format)   {:action=>"random", :controller=>"quotes"}
  search_quotes GET    /search(.:format)   {:action=>"searchform", :controller=>"quotes"}
                POST   /search(.:format)   {:action=>"search", :controller=>"quotes"}
nonsense_quotes GET    /nonsense(.:format) {:action=>"nonsense", :controller=>"quotes"}
    tags_quotes GET    /tags(.:format)     {:action=>"tags", :controller=>"quotes"}
     tag_quotes GET    /tags/:id(.:format) {:action=>"tag", :controller=>"quotes"}
   stats_quotes GET    /stats(.:format)    {:action=>"stats", :controller=>"quotes"}
       up_quote GET    /:id/up(.:format)   {:action=>"up", :controller=>"quotes"}
     down_quote GET    /:id/down(.:format) {:action=>"down", :controller=>"quotes"}
         quotes GET    /                   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"quotes"}
                POST   /                   {:action=>"create", :controller=>"quotes"}
      new_quote GET    /new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"quotes"}
     edit_quote GET    /:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"quotes"}
          quote GET    /:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"quotes"}
                PUT    /:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"quotes"}
                DELETE /:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"quotes"}
           root        /                   {:controller=>"quotes", :action=>"index"}
```

Comment: What is the output of `rake routes CONTROLLER=quotes` ?

Comment: I edited the question with the requested information.

Comment: did you try :format => true ? just shooting from the hip here...

Comment: That actually makes it work less--then every route other than the root routes requires a format and the root routes just don't work at all--they just give me 406 errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so, I've decided that this was probably something that the Rails team did intentionally to discourage URLs like "/.atom" (because really, does that look like something that should happen?), so I'm now using a second route (get "latest", :action => :index) for the format URLs (so, like, "/latest.atom") instead.