# Rails '3.2.10' .js.erb template no route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my public controller I have:

```
  def index
    @super =  "test"
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

I have created a `index.js.erb` for the index action in the views/public folder.

But when I visit `http://localhost:3000/.js`

I get `No route matches [GET] "/.js"`

This have worked before on older version of rails...

Comment: And your question is? Why is it not working? How to make it work? etc.?

Comment: do you make sure that you have <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> in your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

Comment: #1 - Yes what have changed since this gives a route error?

Comment: #2 - Yes it is included..

Comment: who does your route for the index look?

Comment: what's your controller name?

Comment: #3 `root :to => 'public#index'` #4 `PublicController`

Comment: Just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686587/no-format-in-rails-3-1-when-trying-to-route-site-root

Comment: How to add format(s) to the root route?

Comment: You don't want to edit the `root :to`. Because its already pointed to `public/index` file. You can try to create a static controller for static pages and try to point out from the `root :to`

Comment: Created a new action named page and added a new route, and there is added formats

Comment: Instead of giving `root :to => 'public#index'`  just give `root :to => 'index' `

Comment: did you changed to 'index'? any luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This, the very exact, question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686587/no-format-in-rails-3-1-when-trying-to-route-site-root) was asked here a year ago. The asker came to a [conclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7693665/693597), and I quote

> Okay, so, I've decided that this was probably something that the Rails team did intentionally to discourage URLs like "/.atom" (because really, does that look like something that should happen?), so I'm now using a second route (get "latest", :action => :index) for the format URLs (so, like, "/latest.atom") instead.

From the question, it seems it's something happened between 3.0 and 3.1.

As a temporary solution, I still need to go deep, remove `root` from `routes.rb` and add this `get "/(.:format)" instead, to: "public#index"`. This should work.

## Edit

Yup, it could be related to this [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/89c5b9aee7d7db95cec9e5a934c3761872ab107e).

The API specifically [says](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-root) that `root` uses `match` to add `/` to the list of routes. `root` ends with a slash, so ... connect the dots. The commit says no format for routes end with `/`.

I did remove the addition (`|| path.end_with?('/')`) from `actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb` and `root` can now have formats.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you don't break all the calls to the root_path helper, replace the route:

```
root :to => 'public#index'
```

With:

```
get '/(.:format)' => 'public#index', :as => :root
```